# How can I correctly require a file and make use of it's variables?

Tags: php, class, require

I am writing a simple PHP script that make use of DB to export some products. My code starts like

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "";
$pass = "";
$database = "";
```

letting user to add those info. However is there any way to make use configuration.php file that it is saved in the same directory

What I did is this but I didn't got any result

```
require('configuration.php');
echo $user;
```

This is the configuration.php file

```
<?php
class JConfig {
var $dbtype = 'mysql';
var $host = 'localhost';
var $user = 'user';
var $password = 'pass';
var $db = 'db';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a class for the configuration (why ?) then you have to initialize it. or use static class vars.

```
require('configuration.php');

$config = new JConfig;
echo $config->user;
```

you could also use just defines e.g

```
define('DB_USER', 'yourusername');
define('DB_PASS', 'yourpassword');
```

after include/requiring it, you just do:

```
echo DB_USER;
```

Reference : http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

---

EDIT: after your edit i think you mean something diffrent.

you will need 2 config files.
config_default.php
config.php

users write their config in config.php you have yours in config_default.php

you will have to include config_default.php first and than config.php. be notet this only works with variables. if you use classes you will have to write code to init the classes with the correct configuration variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
 class JConfig {
    public static $dbtype = 'mysql';
    public static $host = 'localhost';
    public static $user = 'user';
    public static $password = 'pass';
    public static $db = 'db';
    }
```

and Access direct  in you file were u have included that file

```
JConfig::$user // return 'user'
```

[`Reference`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
require('configuration.php'); 
$config = new JConfig;
echo $config->user;
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't get a result from including/requring your configuriation.php file as it stands, but you've had the right idea.

If you remove the JConfig class wrapper around those variables, you can use them as if they were local variables, once you include/require the file.

`configuration.php`

```
<?php
var $dbtype = 'mysql';
var $host = 'localhost';
var $user = 'user';
var $password = 'pass';
var $db = 'db';
?>
```